# Issue AWS S3 RoutingRules and SSL

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im facing some problems with AWS S3, i figured out that if i set some **RoutingRules**, it will only works at `<bucket_name>.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` endpoint but this endpoint don't have SSL, is there another endpoint that has SSL `s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>` but these RoutingRules doesn't work there.

Is there a way to make RoutingRules works at `s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>` endpoint? or SSL works at `<bucket_name>.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`?

I hear something about **cloudfront** but idk much about.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

`<bucket_name>.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` is a **website** endpoint, whereas the other one is a **REST API** endpoint. You can see the difference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff).

You can see the [example walkthroughs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/hosting-websites-on-s3-examples.html) how to setup a static website on S3 and add CloudFront (where you can add SSL/TLS).

Answer (score -1):

For your use case, as you have already identified you can use AWS CloudFront. It mainly provides two functions,

- Acts as a CDN caching the static content based on your configuration.
- Acts as a proxy where you can connect S3 buckets or other endpoints to CloudFront with routing rules where your DNS points to CloudFront.

In addition you can associate AWS Certificate Manager issued free SSL certificates with CloudFront.

Configuring CloudFront to S3 is straightforward. Check the [AWS Getting Started Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html) for more details.